# Retaining wall back fill/base rock and pool base rock

Tags: pool, retaining-wall, rock

I am installing bevelled retaining wall blocks, 17 inched long, 6 inches high and 12 inches deep.

Trying ti understand material to order.. can i use the same base rock that I use for the back fill? What type of rock shoukd be used. I have a lot of river rock from french drain i wanted to back fill wall with.

I am also looking to put rock tamped as a 4 inch base for pool with foam pad (24ft by 52inches intex) Was hoping to use all the same rock, to get one order... or at least same rock to use for pool base, but not sure of the types to use for each.

This is a dug out on slope for pool, and retaining wall is going around inside wall for pool.

https://imageshack.com/i/pnOhoQpRj

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you're trying to do.  Could you add a sketch?

Comment: Sure i can draw one up, for now i sm attaching some pictures. Retaining eall and pool will be inside dug out area

Answer (score 1):

The rock under the "stack block" wall is different than the rock behind it.

The rock under the wall needs to be crushed rock and compacted. In my area around here, we'd use 1 1/2" minus (with fines) or just 3/4" minus. Compaction is important. Tamp it down or drive on it. (Usually the stack block manufacturers recommend a base course of 8" - 12" deep and a width equal to or greater than the blocks.  Read their instructions.)

The rock behind the wall needs to have lots of voids so water can flow through it.  So, we use river rock (or some call drainrock). It's smooth (from tumbling around in a river for a few centuries) and does NOT compact.

Comment: I know nothing about pool rock, but I suspect you want to compact the rock under your pool.

Comment: Thanks lee. Does the river rock need to be tamped at all when adding? Also, what rock would you recommend under pool?

Comment: River rock can't be compacted. It's like marbles. Just make sure it's contained (in a pit or depression).  Otherwise it will ooze out.   The pool is going to weigh a ton...it needs to sit flat and level and I'd use crushed rock, compacted. Make sure you compact in 6" lifts. That is to say, if you put 12" under your pool, install about 6"" and then compact it. Then do the rest and compact it.

Comment: What is the minimum base height I can use for pool base? Is 4 inches not enough? The dirt is clay, and almost level, just slightly off from dig.  And I can use the type of rock for pool base that I am using for retaining wall base correct? I was thinking of the stuff used under asphault driveways, the crushed rock that is gritty and usually tan in color.

Comment: Yes you can use the same rock under the pool and under the wall. I'm not sure about the color. Here, it's gray.  Tan might be recycle rock, which is cheaper but ok. You want it inorganic.    Are you using a concrete or vinyl in-ground pool.  I think Intel is a vinyl pool and I'm sure they have recommendations on depth of rock, leveling course (sand or foam).  Clay will heave, so make sure you're isolated a bit from it..4"" seems minimal. For footings, we use 12" or so.

Comment: Great, thanks Sam. This is an above ground pool, that's why I was asking if 4" was good enough. It's the intex soft shell pool.

Comment: This is what the place in town has,  https://www.groundeffectsinc.com/product/road-gravel-ca6/  this should work well for the pool and under the retaining wall, correct?

Comment: Also, https://www.groundeffectsinc.com/product/38-limestone-chips-ca16/  i am wondering if thr ca6 will wash away and erode from rain under pool and the ca16 would be better.

Comment: @eaglei22  I can't tell if there are "fines" in the CA16 gravel mix. Fines are used to compact the gravel. Compaction is rated by percentage. Without fines (and an evenly graded mix), I don't think you will get to the 95% compaction ratio recommended. The CA6 seems to have fines and appears to be evenly graded down to sand...this good.

Comment: Do you think the fines would eventually wash away if used under above groind pool? I think the other was recommended under the pool just to let any water flow under and drain away, i am going to do my best to displace the water though before it gets under there. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @eaglei22   The fill must be "contained". That is to say, the fill can't allow water to flow through the fill or it will wash away. Usually, the fill is placed in a hole that has been dug down below finish grade.